# Folder accessible by all, children folder only by users in groups

Tags: linux, chmod, chown

I'm creating an application and I need to allow user to read in folder when I allow us.

Architecture :

`BOSS FOLDER (root:root) 777
        CHILD1 (root:child1)  ???
        CHILD2 (root:child2)  ???
        CHILD3 (root:child3)  ???`

So, BOSS is accessible by all and CHILD only by users in group "child", i need CHILD folder not visible if users not in "child".

How to make that ???

Comment: Define *visible*.

Comment: I don't understand !

Comment: What is *visible* in your question: you want to hide directories completely, or want to restrict access to their contents?

Comment: Ok, sorry. They only can access and view child folder where they are in the group of this folder.

Comment: POST edited, my mistake

Comment: So you basically answered your own question. You need to create one group per folder. Each group should have permissions of `770`, which means only `root` and group members have read, write, and execute permissions on particular directory.
Also, it is more secure to create a parent group `children` with all users that should have permissions under your `BOSS` folder, and make it look like this: `BOSS root:children 770`. This way you will avoid public access to your `BOSS` folder.

Comment: In any case, file/directory permissions is something that any IT related person needs to know. Read this: https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions

Comment: Ok thx, going to read this. Soon

Answer (score 0):

If users from child group need write permission then child folder permission should be 770 otherwise for read only permission it should 750 on child folder.

BOSS FOLDER (root:root) 777
        CHILD (root:child) 770 (750 for read only access by child group)

Answer (score 0):

Just disable access for other users, i.e.:

```
chmod o-rwx CHILD
```

The CHILD folder will be visible though, but it will be inaccessible for users not in "child" group. IMO there is no way to make the folder invisible.

Comment: Even if parent folder doesn't allow to reach child folder without permission ?

Comment: You are right. I might misunderstood the question. Everyone has an access to the BOSS (parent) folder, so everyone will see (list) the CHILD folder there. Only "child" group users will be able to read CHILD folder content, so only if there is a child_file.txt in CHILD folder, only "child" group users will see it.